# Plugin [ingest-geoip] was built for Elasticsearch version 6.2.4 but version 6.5.0 is running

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-6

I am using ELK for monitoring. It was working fine a few days ago and suddenly stopped working.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Error log:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin [ingest-geoip] was built
>   for Elasticsearch version 6.2.4 but version 6.5.0 is running
>           at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.verifyCompatibility(PluginsService.java:339)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:524)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:464)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.(PluginsService.java:156)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:338) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:265) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:212)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333)
>   [elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136)
>   [elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127)
>   [elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
>   [elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
>   [elasticsearch-cli-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
>   [elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86)
>   [elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0] [2018-11-15T23:33:31,908][WARN
>   ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [97v4l7O] uncaught
>   exception in thread [main]
>   org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin [ingest-geoip] was built
>   for Elasticsearch version 6.2.4 but version 6.5.0 is running
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:140)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
>   ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin [ingest-geoip] was built
>   for Elasticsearch version 6.2.4 but version 6.5.0 is running
>           at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.verifyCompatibility(PluginsService.java:339)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:524)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:464)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.(PluginsService.java:156)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:338) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.(Node.java:265) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.(Bootstrap.java:212)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136)
>   ~[elasticsearch-6.5.0.jar:6.5.0]
>           ... 6 more

Comment: You've upgraded from 6.2.4 to 6.5.0 but forgot to upgrade the plugins?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I haven't upgraded manually, seems its upgraded automatically. How to fix this?

Comment: I've never heard of automatic upgrades... Where is your ES hosted?

Comment: I hosted that in AWS.

Comment: on your own EC2 instances or are you using the AWS hosted ES Service?

Comment: It is in my own ec2 instance, In that, I installed ELK and APM-Server.

Comment: Ok, then I doubt the upgrade was automatic, there's a process to follow when upgrading, so someone might have done it for you, but it's not automatic.

Comment: Ok, Do you any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Somehow, you've upgraded from 6.2.4 to 6.5.0 but forgot to upgrade the plugins.

To fix this problem simply run the following two commands:

```
$ sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin remove ingest-geoip
$ sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-geoip
```

**UPDATE**: Worth noting that as of ES 6.7, `ingest-geoip` will be a [full-fledge module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/breaking-changes-6.7.html#_literal_ingest_geoip_literal_and_literal_ingest_user_agent_literal_are_no_longer_distributed_as_plugins) of ES and won't need to be installed as a plugin anymore.

Comment: How did you install ES? Via a tarball or RPM/DEB?

Comment: Installed via RPM.

Comment: Then you can cd into `/usr/share/elasticsearch` and then run the commands from there

Comment: Thanks a lot, Elasticsearch is started running but While running kibana in browser I am getting this "Kibana server is not ready yet"

Comment: I invite you to ask a new question since this is related to a different issue.

Comment: Thanks. It helps. Just once notice. I had to delete the plugin folder from /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/6.8.8/libexec/plugins to make it reinstall the new version.